# why my notifications don't appear at the specified time

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

i want show notification using alarm manager, but the notification doesnt appear at the specified time,the notification instead appears when data is saved

here my code of scheduledNotification method

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, Calendar calendar) {


        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublish.class);
        notifIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublish.NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notifIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublish.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddTaskActivity.this, 0, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

//        long futureInMilis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

and is the getNotification method

```
private Notification getNotification(String task) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(task);
        builder.setContentText("Go Start");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Here is Calendar set

```
 public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
                        String date3 = sdf.format(date);
//                        time = date.getTime();
                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDay());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.getHours());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());
                        edt_datepicker.setText(date3);
                    }
                }).display();
```

and this onClick for save data

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btn_add_task){
            addTask();
            scheduleNotification(getNotification(task),calendar);
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
```

and this is class BroadCastReceiver

```
public class NotificationPublish extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification_id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ONRECEIVE", "CALLED");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        manager.notify(id, notification);
    }
}
```

Calendar import is java.util.Calendar

I have searched and tried one, it still does not work,,I need ur help

Thanks

Comment: Do you use emulator or a real device?

Answer (score 0):

define importance of notification. refer above link

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Priority

```
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
```

Comment: If you are using android 7 or lower version then you can setPriority() of notification. refer link : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority(int)

Comment: but thats not what i need